# Remove apache's DirectoryIndex

Tags: apache-2.2

Is it possible to turn apache's `DirectoryIndex` off for specific directory using `.htaccess` file? I've tried `DirectoryIndex Off` but if file `Off` exists it uses it as index file. I want to make sure that the directory will be listed no matter what files are inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Set `DirectoryIndex` to a filename that will never possibly exist.

   ```
   DirectoryIndex lni345hoqvgheruhgreoiuhgeroi30948yt0348
   ```
2. Don't load the `mod_dir` module. This, however, will disable the `index.html` style functionality for the entire server, and is probably not what you want.

[Beginning with Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) you can set `DirectoryIndex disabled` to disable its functionality.

Answer (score 8):

According to the documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectoryIndex), you can use:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

to do this, either in your Apache config file, or in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Not available in 2.2, you seem to need 2.4 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax would be to disable indexes via options

```
Options -Indexes
```

Of course for this to work you need to have at least `AllowOverride Indexes` or `AllowOverride all` for this directory in order to have power to change this option via *.htaccess* in given directory.

Comment: I don't think you read his question correctly. He _wants_ Indexes to _always_ be displayed, even if the directory contains an `index.html` or similar file.

Comment: question is vague, I explained how directory indexes are disabled.

Comment: Vague? The question was perfectly clear.

Comment: He want's directory indexes off, but he wants them displayed... displayed from where? display what? indexes, random document if no files?

Comment: "I want to make sure that the directory will be listed no matter what files are inside."  I.e. the behavior with +Indexes, not -Indexes.  You explained how to disable directory indexing (the desired behavior), not the Apache DirectoryIndex directive (which loads a file instead of showing the directory index).

Answer (score -1):

```
Options +Indexes                                                     
DirectoryIndex yduien48fj5ntug7rntih7hrfjgmiy
```

These two lines added to your .htaccess file will, in combination, display everything in the directory.  The index file is set to the nonsensical name which does not exist, so the +Indexes will be invoked, and your real index.php (index.html, etc.) will be listed along with any other files in the directory.

Comment: This is already stated in the accepted answer. However, by 2018 you should be on Apache 2.4, in which case there is no need for any "hacks" - simply set `DirectoryIndex disabled`.

Comment: @MrWhite  That seems unfair.  This answer is the only one that notes that to get the directory index listing, you need +Indexes.  That appears in no other answer, although it is of course required for the requested result (it's possible that Apache will default to it).  It's also worth noting that another "answer" incorrectly says -Indexes, which of course won't give the requested result.